# C# div InnerHtml from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my program I have the following in my Site.Master

```
<div id="programs" runat="server">
```

and the following c#

```
programs.InnerHtml += $"<div style=\"width:80px; height:50px; align:center;\">{reader[1]}</div>";
```

Basically I have currently 2 programs listed in my db. I want to list each one side by side and any subsequent ones I may add in the future. when I use the += I get an error

> Cannot get inner content of programs because the contents are not
>   literal.

when I remove it gives me only the last record (which is expected).

Any ideas why I'm getting this error and what I can do to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Controls.Add()` try use this code

```
var x =$"<div style=\"width:80px; height:50px; align:center;\">{reader[1]}</div>";

programs.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(x));
```